# Custom Grunt task won't run

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to create a grunt file where I am able to run a custom build task followed by the default task.

The custom task is run after first install of the site and contains some basic setup tasks for compiling sass, minifying css and javascript. After this is run I will then run the default task which simply contains watch and will watch for changes in various files, sass, html, js etc.

Here's some code for you that I've tried to implement...

```
// Custom Grunt task to run after install
grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass', 'cssmin', 'uglify']);

// Set default tasks to perform on 'grunt' command
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
```

Basically I want to run once `grunt build` followed by `grunt` which will constantly poll for changes throughout the rest of the projects life. At the end of the project I also want to have another custom task `grunt imagemin` which will compress all the project images ready for dist. My project is then set up and ready to rock, but I'm getting back the error:

```
$ grunt build
Warning: Task "build" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I don't know what's wrong. Please let me know if you need to see the rest of the file, just trying to keep it simple.

Many thanks,

Dan

Comment: I always put custom tasks after the default task - check to see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @TaniaRascia. I've made that change and have run the command `grunt build` again, but no joy :(

Comment: Do you have all your `grunt.loadNpmTasks('tasks');` set for the `build` task? It might not work if it's missing one. You're loading the task fine so we'll need to see more code.

Comment: [Here is an article](http://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-grunt-and-sass/) I wrote about setting up exactly what you have. Look at my Grunt file and see if what you have is drastically different. There is likely a problem with your syntax somewhere. Additionally, you don't need to run two tasks - your watch should be using sass, cssmin, and uglify.

Comment: That looks like a great resource @TaniaRascia, thank you for that. I have bookmarked it :) And I will swipe your config for posts while i'm there ;) My 'watch' task does indeed include sass, cosmic etc in there, but it is watching for changes. I load a new project with no CSS precompiled, so this separate task is there to run all that guff just initially, then 'watch' will detect the changes ongoing after that...

Comment: I am wondering if it is because I am not actually using the loadNpmTask, but instead using 'matchdep' which, when included at the start of the grunt file, will generate all those for you without the need for manually typing them all out.

Comment: Not sure which config you're referring to, but feel free to swipe whatever you wish. :) Your `grunt-sass` plugin is better than the `grunt-contrib-sass` that I'm using in that example, but otherwise everything there will guide you.

Comment: I would attempt to do it manually for debugging sake.

Comment: Here's a fiddle of my Gruntfile: https://jsfiddle.net/887epqun/

Comment: The way your watch is set up, it should be doing everything you want your build to do.